# Using index on datetime field not working really

Tags: mysql, index

Here is my query

```
select msisdn, sum(score) as score 
from contest_player_update_history_ideacontest6_35 
where request_date >='2015-01-14 00:00:00' 
  and request_date <= '2015-02-03 23:59:59' 
group by msisdn;

CREATE TABLE `contest_player_update_history_ideacontest6_35` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msisdn` varchar(15) DEFAULT '',
  `request_id` bigint(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `contest_id` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `request_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `operator` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `circle` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `short_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `channel` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `score` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `request_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `request_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ans_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `qusetion_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `time_taken` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `billing_amount` double(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `billing_validity` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `operation` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `param` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `param1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `param2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `param3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `question_level` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `max_allowed_question` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `allowed_question_per_day` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdn` (`msisdn`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `request_date` (`request_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Explain gives me

```
 1  SIMPLE       contest_player_update_history_ideacontest6_35  range   request_date   request_date  9        (NULL)  5365990  Using where
```

when date range is request_date >='2015-01-14 00:00:00' and request_date <= '2015-02-03 23:59:59' Here key **request_date** key is being used.

and when I change the date range just includes another day 
request_date >='2015-01-14 00:00:00' and request_date <= '2015-02-04 23:59:59', No key is being used and whole table is being traversed which causing delay in query. And data selection goes from 5 million to 20 million just adding 1 day since whole table is being traversed.

explain gives me result as

```
1  SIMPLE       contest_player_update_history_ideacontest6_35  ALL     request_date   (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  27221681  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: This seems to indicate that the 2nd range is not selective enough to use the index *5365990* vs. * 27221681* estimated rows. But a *covering* index on including both `request_date` and `score` should always be used.

Comment: I will try the composite index on request_date and score and will share the results.

Comment: Several possible answers...  Statistics are out of date; see if the `EXPLAIN` changes after doing `ANALYZE TABLE`.  (Caveat; this is slow on MyISAM.)  Switch to InnoDB, things are better handled there.  What % of the table is in that month?

Answer (score 1):

Using an index involves back-and-forth between the index BTree and the data BTree. So, if more than something like 20% of the table needs to be looked at, it is faster to simply scan the data (ignoring the index) and filter out those that fail the WHERE clause.

Comment: You can force using index by add hints into select, as well is good idea test few variants with index for msisdn, group by on 5M rows without indexes take also many time